# Regex: Remove postfix string in any word after occurance of any of list of strings in a paragraph

Tags: java, regex, string, string-matching

I have a bigger string and a list of strings. I want to change the bigger string such that
- For any occurrence of a string in list in a bigger string, remove the suffix part till next space.

> Bigger String

```
WITH dataTab0 AS (SELECT TO_CHAR(to_date(tab_0_0.times),'YYYYMMDD')  AS TIME_ID_CATEGORYe93bc60a0041,tab_0_0.request_id AS PAGE_IMPRESSIONf6beefc4b44e4b  FROM full_contents_2
```

> List

```
TIME_ID_CATEGORY
PAGE_IMPRESSION
...
```

I need to remove suffix like e93bc60a0041 and f6beefc4b44e4b which is coming after TIME_ID_CATEGORY and PAGE_IMPRESSION

I expect following result. I need regex based/effective solution in java to achieve the same.

```
WITH dataTab0 AS (SELECT TO_CHAR(to_date(tab_0_0.times),'YYYYMMDD')  AS TIME_ID_CATEGORY,tab_0_0.request_id AS PAGE_IMPRESSION  FROM full_contents_2
```

Comment: Not a fixed list, it can be close to 100.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this? Essentially matching TIME_ID_CATEGORY or PAGE_IMPRESSION into Group 1, and anything that follows (i.e. suffix) as Group 2.

```
(TIME_ID_CATEGORY|PAGE_IMPRESSION)(\w+)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JFkqEe/1/)

And then simply replace contents of Group 2 with empty string. Or just replace with Group 1, this will also get rid of the suffix (see below code snippet).

Example code snippet:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    String line = "WITH dataTab0 AS (SELECT TO_CHAR(to_date(tab_0_0.times),'YYYYMMDD')  AS TIME_ID_CATEGORYe93bc60a0041,tab_0_0.request_id AS PAGE_IMPRESSIONf6beefc154b44e4b  FROM full_contents_2";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(TIME_ID_CATEGORY|PAGE_IMPRESSION)(\\w+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    if (m.find()) {
        String output = m.replaceAll("$1");
        System.out.println(output);
        //WITH dataTab0 AS (SELECT TO_CHAR(to_date(tab_0_0.times),'YYYYMMDD')  AS TIME_ID_CATEGORY,tab_0_0.request_id AS PAGE_IMPRESSION  FROM full_contents_2

    }

}
```

Comment: What does the $1 mean here.

Comment: @vinoth10 this refers to the Group - $1 is Group 1, $2 would be Group 2.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that maybe a simple expression,

```
[a-f0-9]{14}
```

replaced with an empty string might actually work here, if we only have those 14-length substrings.

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/OQW85T/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/OQW85T/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: Its not fixed to 14 digits.